# How to make DropdownButtonFromField with API using riverpod?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I don't know to make DropdownButtonFromField with API using ref watch and read. Can you help me to resolve?  this is my code in the pages

```dart
class MyDropdownButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _kandang = ref.watch(kandangProvider).getKandang();
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: LimitedContainer(
        limitWidth: maxScreenWidth,
        child: BackStack(
          showBackButton: true,
          children: [
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(formPadding),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 5,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: 400,
                        height: 60,
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                        child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                          decoration: kTextFiledInputDecoration.copyWith(
                              labelText: "Kode Kandang"),
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            print(value);
                          },
                          items: value.kandang.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
                            (e) {
                              return DropdownMenuItem(
                                child: Text(e.kode_kandang as String),
                                value: e.kode_kandang as String,
                              );
                            },
                          ).toList(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I already to try using that, but I find to problem error

Comment: I think it would be better with futureProvider, then map>> whenData

Comment: I want to using ref.watch and ref.read in my code, but I don't know using dropdownbuttonfromfield. can you help me?

Comment: does your dropdown changed print the value?

Comment: yes, dropdown change of field API changes

Comment: use a nullable value on `DropdownButtonFormField` and assign it on `onChanged`.

Comment: can you give me example?